# How to remotely debug Python with IntelliJ?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, intellij-idea

Is there a way for remotely debugging Python3 with IntelliJ? I couldn't find any options for it. With VS Code, it's as simple as having this file:

##### launch.json

```
     {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "connect": {
                "host": "172.18.0.5",
                "port": 5678
            },
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "remoteRoot": "."
                }
            ],
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

and everything works like a (py)charm!

How can i do it with IntelliJ?

I examined all of JetBrains' tutorials, but none seemed to fit what I was searching for.

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ IDEA and PyCharm both support **Remote Debugging with Python**, just follow the guide here:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html

If you are using IntelliJ IDEA, you may install the Python plugin first, by **Settings > Plugins > Marketplace**, inputting `Python`, and then clicking the **Install** button.

And here is the step to step guide on **Remote debugging with the Python remote debug server configuration** https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html#remote-debug-config:

1. Let IDEA/PyCharm host a debugger server on the machine your IDE runs on locally:

Note: This step is a lot different compared with VS Code(Sorry I know little about that tool), in VS Code it's using the package https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy, but it first will call `python -m debugpy --listen 0.0.0.0:5678 ./myscript.py` to create a debug server on the remote machine/docker, then the Client(here is VS Code) connect to it. But in IDEA/PyCharm it's just the opposite: Python Debug server is listening on the local machine, and the remote script will connect to the IDE's server.

From the main menu, choose **Run| Edit Configuration....** The Run/debug configurations dialog opens. You have to click Add configuration on the toolbar, and from the list of available configurations, select **Python Debug Server**.

[image]

Please change the port to a different number between 0 and 65535, default value `0` will not work here, then remember the steps above the `IDE host name` area.

More info about the `IDE host name`:  the user may specify another host if the debug server is not in the same machine (default is the `localhost`). In your case you want to connect it from a container, you may change it to the IP of your current machine.

You may also set up the **Path Mapping:** by clicking the folder selector and then selecting the real folder path as ${workspaceFolder}.

Then click `OK` button to save it, and then you click the run button to let the debug server run up and listen on remote code to connect to it, it will display something like this in the `Debug` tool window:

```
Starting debug server at port 12,345
Waiting for process connection…
Use the following code to connect to the debugger:
import pydevd_pycharm
pydevd_pycharm.settrace('some ip address', port=12345, stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True)
```

2. Install and run debug server client in remote machine/container

On your container, execute the following one-time commands in the terminal(In case you are using IDE 2022.3):
`pip3 install pydevd-pycharm~=223.8214.51`

Then modify the Python file you want to debug by adding lines at the begging of the source file(THIS STEP IS MANDATORY), for eg:

```
#==============this code added==================================================================:
import pydevd_pycharm

pydevd_pycharm.settrace('some ip address', port=12345, stdoutToServer=True,
                        stderrToServer=True)
                        
# ... The other codes remain as is
```

Then you may start remote debugging by just executing the below command in the terminal of the remote machine/container:
`python3 myfile.py`

3. Return to the local IDE and begin debugging

Just after step 2, now the local IDE will begin the debugging.

And the final result may look like this:

[image]

Comment: and, do u really think i did not looked at the first result in google before writing this question?

Comment: @Dima The guide works but it is really a bit hard to follow, hope this really could help you and I've updated the detailed step on how to do it

Comment: u just copied the guide here?

i did not ask how to run a new debug server, i asked how to connect to already remote one.

Comment: No, in fact, I tried the Microsoft solution that was built on top of `debugpy`, so I'd let to tell you that the remote debug function is not built into python, it's a 3rd party function provided by different vendors, and you can't connect JetBrains IDE to a remote debug server `debugpy` provided by Microsoft's de buggy and vise-visa. It will not be working that way. So even VS Code workings with its own remote debug protocol, will not work in IDEA.

Comment: Too bad, the VsCode solution is pretty clean.